# Adding Color Swatches

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.2.0, swatches

I want to use swatches on site, after reading various posts, the option in the admin site is listed on the left hand navigation is missing. I am currently using CE 1.9.2, I recently upgraded from 1.9.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

S

Comment: Sounds like the module is deactivated. Check the files in `app/etc/modules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. It was down to permissions on the .xml file and the folder structure.